# Why does using android studio overrides cant upload after install blank?

Tags: android, android-studio

i am using android studio 3.2
i create self this project but i got messages like this
where is wrong text?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public static final String PAGE_URL  = "http://noah.com/index.php";
    WebView webb;
    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private WebView webView;
    private WebSettings webSettings;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;

    // ...
}
```

i got message like this :
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: Android Studio shows such errors in some context. It would be helpful to not only provide part of source code, but to point out which line it is about deprecated feature.